# Need help understanding line # 9 of is_prime function; is there a simpler way for the function?

Tags: python-2.7, function, simplify

How is line # 9(if n + 1 == x) relevant to checking if the number is prime?

Is there a simpler way to build this function?

```
    def is_prime(x):
        if x == 2:
            return True
        elif x > 2:
            for n in range(2, x):
                if x % n == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    if n + 1 == x:
                        return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: `if n + 1 == x` simply checks whether the current number `n` is one less than the target number `x`. If you've got all the way to the number just before `x` without finding a number that divides into it (actually not even that far, there are plenty of optimisations), how can `x` be anything other than prime?

Comment: @jonrsharpe unless the OP is asking what's the point of that block? I suppose one could just remove it and `return True` after the `for` directly instead of that rather weird check...

Comment: @JonClements yeah, it's not a great example of the prime checking art!

Comment: I'm teaching myself Python; as with anything else I've ever taught myself I'm approaching it from several angles at once. Codecademy is one of those angles. This is my umpteenth time through Codecademy's python course, and this is the only problem out of the entire course that I don't understand--the above answer is someone else's, not mine, and I don't understand how the function works, specifically, line # 9.

Comment: And this is the only answer that Codecademy will accept as correct, that I can find. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prime number is an integer having only 1 and 'self' as divisors. Here is a similar solution that may be easier to follow. We use a pandas DataFrame and it's associated 'apply' function. Suppress the 'print df' line and modify the output as desired. Have fun

```
"""
Created on Fri Nov 18 13:32:08 2016
@author: Soya
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame, Series


def isprime(x):
    vals = range(2,x/2)
    df = DataFrame([vals]).T
    df['1'] = df.apply(lambda y: x%y)
    print df
    print ''
    if df['1'].prod() != 0:
        print 'PRIME'

isprime(17)
   0  1
0  2  1
1  3  2
2  4  1
3  5  2
4  6  5
5  7  3

PRIME
```